# How does completablefuture works?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, forkjoinpool, worker-thread

Need to know the insights of the complete future task without an executor.

Here is my sample code

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    dosomething();
});
```

How is this task assigned to the thread? Do we have any size for the waiting queue and the thread count?

Comment: "I know it is a mean question though." - Actually, it is hard to answer because it is nect to impossible to understand what you are asking.  But I will do my best (in comments).

Comment: "How does completablefuture works with worker thread?" A worker thread executes the task,

Comment: "It will be invoked more often."  - Unclear what you are asking?  What is "it"?  More often than what?  But I can tell you that `dosomething();` will be invoked exactly one time for each time that your sample code runs.

Comment: "what happens when the threads there is no free thread?" If the thread pool below its max thread limit, a new thread is created and added to the pool.  Otherwise the task is put into the queue.

Comment: "what happens when the threads there is no free thread?" - It depends.  See above.

Comment: "how to check the implementation of forkjoinpool" - Download the OpenJDK source code, then locale and read the files you are interested in.   (Or google for the source code for the class.)

Comment: "how does task get assigned to thread" - the thread pool assigns it. Basically, it sees that there is a free worker, and a task on the queue, and it assigns the task to the worker. (If there is a free worker and nothing in the queue, the task might get assigned without going through the queue,  Check the source code if you *really* think you need to know this.  I don't think you do ...)

Comment: No disrespect meant to @StephenC, but if your program depends on a thread pool behaving in a particular way, then you had better explicitly specify a thread pool that is _documented_ to behave in the way that you need, or else use a thread pool that you implemented for yourself. Reading the OpenJDK source is a great way to learn how things work in general, but there's no guarantee that every environment in which your code runs will use  the exact same JDK version whose source you read.

Comment: @StephenC Can you let me know why you felt like this `Actually, it is hard to answer because it is nect to impossible to understand what you are asking` 

And also thanks for providing the insights.

Comment: See JDK source code, in JDK21, for my particular installation, `runAsync` uses either `CompletableFuture$ThreadPerTaskExecutor` (ie new thread each time, no pool) or `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` (and javadoc says "new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the calling thread, at the discretion of the Executor implementation").

Comment: @div "Can you let me know why you felt like this" - It should be clear from the comments following that one.  In general, if I'm having to ask you what you mean, then *ipso facto* I can't figure out what you are actually asking.   And your apparent obsession with thread counts, etc also makes me wonder what you mental model is ... which also makes it difficult to answer effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [CompletableFuture javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync-java.lang.Runnable-)?

**public static CompletableFuture runAsync(Runnable runnable)**

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a
> task running in the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() after it runs the given
> action.

**public static CompletableFuture runAsync(Runnable runnable, Executor executor)**

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a
> task running in the given executor after it runs the given action.

See also [ForkJoinPool javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)

Comment: Yes and What will be the thread count in that commonpool? and how to check the implementation of forkjoinpool ?

Comment: I'd imagine this would be up to the host environment (a 16 core machine might have more threads in the pool than a mobile phone). Have you tried calling `ForkJoinPool.commonPool().getPoolSize()`? If you want full control over this, pass an `Executor` to `runAsync(...)`  instead of using the "common pool". For example `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)` will create a pool of 5 threads

Comment: @div, "What will be the thread count in that commonpool?" You don't get to know. If you need to know precisely how many threads are created by the pool, then don't use the common pool. Use `runAsync(runnable, executor)`, and provide an `executor` that gives you the control that you need.

Comment: The fork/join pool doesn’t have a fixed thread count. It has a target *parallelism* setting which determines, how many *active* threads it wants to have. So, if threads are known to be blocked, it may start more threads to compensate. The default parallelism for the common pool is “number of CPU cores minus one”.